ComposeView inside BottomSheetDialog, ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found issue
I'm getting the below issue
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from android.widget.FrameLayout{f3988c2 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b0570 app:id/container}
for the below code.
Note: I'm not using a fragment
        val bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(activity)
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.confirmation_sheet, null)

        view.findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.compose_container).setContent { }


What version of AppCompat are you using?

App compat version is 1.6.1
